# How do I generate ID when I have composite keys in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a `Entity` with composite keys. See below:

```
class BankAccount {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * 
     */
    protected $bank;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyBundle\Entity\Company")
     */
    protected $company;

    ...

}
```

because Doctrine has some issues with composite keys it won't generates sequences (I'm working in PostgreSQL), how do I deal with this in order to generate `$bank` which is the PK?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question - please clarify. you can't use `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` for the primary key with postgresql and are looking for a way to generate the id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sounds like you don't want a composite key, just a primary key on `$bank` and a foreign key on `$company`. If that's the case,

```
class BankAccount {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $bank;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyBundle\Entity\Company")
     */
    protected $company;

    ...

}
```

should do it.